# API via Web: use 80 port or a custom one (like 8080)?

Tags: java, http

We have a web service that won't be accessed by human users. I.e. only by:

1. Javascript from a browser
2. Mobile applications (iPhone & Android)
3. Other servers

The question: is it OK to use some custom port for this (like 8080) or we should use only 80 port (so the URL won't contain the port number).

What are the pros and cons? Are there any reasons why the option with custom ports is unacceptable?

Comment: Should this be tagged javascript and not java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If some of your clients are behind a firewall they may have policies that restrict access to 'non-standard ports', including port 8080. Apart from that I do not see any cons to running your web service endpoints on port 8080. A pro is that if you want to run a regular web server on the same machine you can assign it port 80 with no conflicts.

Moving the service to another port doesn't increase your security risk any more than having it on the original port. Running on port 8080 shouldn't affect any mobile devices, as long as their ISP doesn't block the port.

Comment: May any problem arise on mobile phones? On only on browser javascript because of proxies? What about opening an extra port on the server - does it expose to any vulnerability?

Comment: Moving the service to another port doesn't increase your security risk any more than having it on the original port. Running on port 8080 shouldn't affect any mobile devices, as long as their ISP doesn't block the port.

Answer (score 4):

One pro of not having it on a default port is that its less likely to get unwanted traffic.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is set up your own firewall or router to route traffic addressed to a specific url to a custom port set up on your app server, so that only requests specific to the service you run hit it.